# Getting the average of multiple variables in a single column SQL

Tags: sql

I want to get the average length of stay for each admission to each hospital.

```
SELECT fake_hospitalName, fake_los
from fakehospitalfacility, fakeadmission
where ((fake_doa2 >= 100101) and (fake_doa2 <= 101231));
```

However, everytime I use the average command, I get the average length of stay of all the admissions to all the hospitals.

```
SELECT fake_hospitalName, avg(fake_los)
from fakehospitalfacility, fakeadmission
where ((fake_doa2 >= 100101) and (fake_doa2 <= 101231))
group by fake_hosptialName;
```

The image shows part of a table where I extrapolated each length of stay for each admission.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: The average los of each visit is the los.  Perhaps you should clarify the requirements with your customer.

Comment: Simply add another group by column for whatever defines *admission* maybe, `fakeadmission.id`.

Comment: Also, what is the relationship between *hospital* and *admission*? Even in your supposed implicit join with commas, you do not have a `WHERE` condition on ids. Hence this is really a [cross join](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm) with data filtering.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: No join condition?